# Configuring Cassandra on AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I think I mis-configured listen_address, rpc_address and seed addresses for my present setup.
The scenario is this: I have 3 node cassandra cluster inside AWS vpc with two ips for each node - on public, one private.

Lets say the three nodes have the following public, private ips
nodeA: (pubA, pvtA)
nodeB: (pubB, pvtB)
nodeC: (pubC, pvtC)

In the cassandra.yaml, I gave:

- seed addresses:         pvtA, pvtB
- listen_address:           pvtA/pvtB/pvtC
- rpc_address:              0.0.0.0
- broadcast_address:   commented
- endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
- Authentication: PasswordAuthenticator

Now, my clients are applications on heroku trying to connect to the (pubA,pubB,pubC). The connection get only to the first seed pubA and I see a errors connecting to and finding other nodes using pvtB, pvtC addresses. The queries/IO go as expected but I think all the traffic is only hitting one node at pubA.

I tried using all pvt addresses as the internal network traffic on these interfaces is secure and not billed. Is there a way to let the clients connect to other nodes using their public addresses?